# Select count doesnt returns all rows in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do have a table in the database, which supposed to have more than 1k rows. The DB is Postgress. I use the following command:

`select count(*) from icdten;` it returns 1000 which is wrong

and also

`select * from icdten;`

returns the first 1000 rows, which is wrong I want to have all of them. Googling didnt find, or maybe I was googling the wrong thing.

EDIT1: I use PgAdmin, maybe it is PgAdmin issue.. I just did not find that option looking through the interface. It supposed to have 14k rows.

Comment: How do you know there are more than 1000 rows?

Comment: @Arun, I had it before, just doesnt remember where I should turn off that option, the limit of 1k. It should have 14k rows

Comment: The table hasn't been renamed and a view put in it's place that limits the rows returned?

Comment: how do you know there are more ? what do you use to run the query ? in some software there is a limit on the number of rows back. That said , it should effect the result of `select count(*)`

Comment: Is there a server (or client library) setting to limit the output to a maximum number? I know this from SQL-Server libraries to limit the bandwidth... But, how this would limit the 'select count(*)'???

Comment: updated, have a look at my post. @alzaimar

Comment: The limit of 1k is for the number of rows returned per SQL. In your count(*), the result set is just one. The limit will not get affected here. I think your table has only 1000 rows

Comment: Maybe you should check the metadata in the system catalog; the table describing the `icdten` table may have a number of rows listed, which would provide a cross-check on your assertion that there should be 14k rows, give or take.  Maybe the (semi-hypothetical) 1000-row limit meant that the table load process was stopped after 1000 rows, so that the table really does only contain 1000 rows, even though there were 14k to be loaded.

Comment: ide's like squirrel limit the number of return result , if you start working with big data you understand this is needed, check the next link, in the upper right corner http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/screenshots/5_codecompletion.png

Comment: @Mzf, seems it is PGAdmin is shitty, as I dont have that option here.. I looked all the way in the options, but didnt get that limit place.. seems need to change it or update.

Comment: Okay, to get PGAdmin out of the race, maybe it would be a good idea to try another query tool, such as the standard `psql` available in every postgresql installation.

Comment: One more idea: Try to vacuum your table, just in case some statistics are wrong.

Comment: @Thilo: `SELECT count(*) FROM tbl` *actually* counts rows and does not rely on table statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Possible limit is set in PgAdmin. Please look at Options/Query tab of PgAdmin like described in http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/options-tab3.html (http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/options-tab4.html for version 1.16 you mentioned):

Maximum rows to retrieve can be set to 1000 (default is 100, people usually change this value), and also "Count rows if estimated less than" may affect to COUNT function (it can use count from table statistics instead of real table count, so try to set temporary this value to a big number)

Comment: what version is that? I dont have it in my version. Mean the field "Maximum rows to be returned".. My version is 1.16

Comment: This is totally link only answer. Can you please add an actual answer here? Because the answer you have linked seems correct to me.

Comment: Answer extended, link to documentation for you concrete product version is also added.

Comment: Ok, something strange with my PgAdmin. It looks different then in picture, but the version is 1.16.. Anyway, what you mean by `Maximum rows to retrieve can be set to 1000` when I want to have 14k... I will update pgAdmin..

Comment: I mean that it can already be set to 1000 and you must change this value to 15000 at least to check is this option affects.

Comment: pgAdmin can limit the number of rows returned, but it would *never* return a wrong number for `select count(*) from icdten`. This cannot be the explanation. `Count rows if estimated less than` only sets a limit when to count automatically. It *never* returns a wrong count when you execute the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to troubleshoot this issue:

1. First try from psql.  While select count(*) should give you the same on both, maybe there is something going on.  Also there is no limit there, so you can:

   ```
   \o testfile
   \i select * from icdten
   \q (exits psql)
   wc -l testfile
   ```
2. If that still shows 1000 rows then you probably have 1000 rows in that table, start making sure you are connected to the right db, querying the table you think you are, etc.

   ```
   EXPLAIN ANALYSE
   ```

May be helpful in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. It's simply a default parameter set in some versions of PostgreSQL.
You can change the parameter by going to the PostgreSQL's installation directory and navigating to `pgAdmin 4\web`. The directory for version 12 looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web
```

Open `config.py` with a text editor and search for `ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT`. It is initially set to `1000`.

```
##########################################################################
# Number of records to fetch in one batch in query tool when query result
# set is large.
##########################################################################
ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT = 1000
```

You can comment this line out but it could result in other errors. I would suggest to change it to a large value like 10,000,000. If you can't save the file after the modification you need to copy the file somewhere else, make the changes and save, then copy back to the original folder and replace with the original file.